# Linq dynamic where clause query to find rows which contains 1st charater is numeric

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, dynamic

I have following code to find where clause to search rows which contains numeric on first character of column
if you have solutions please reply. below code result but only single row is returning

```
var strs = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
query = query.Where("@0.Contains(Name.Substring(0,1))", strs);
query = query.Where("Name.Substring(0,1).Contains(@0)", strs);
query = query.Where("Name.Contains(@0)", strs);
query.Where("Name.StartsWith(\"[0-9]\")");
```

Comment: Post full code, where is it exactly returning a single row?

Comment: Have you tried approaching it from the strs side? Make strs a string and use strs.Contains(Name.Substring(0,1))?

Comment: Sql Query is SELECT Name FROM Organization WHERE LEFT(Name,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
SELECT Name FROM Organization WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(Name,1) )= 1

Comment: @TigOldBitties I am using System.Linq.Dynamic for dynamic where condition everything is working expect this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
query = query.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.Name.Substring(0, 1))", (object)strs);
```

There are two Dynamic LINQ specifics.

First, the last argument of most of the dynamic methods is declared as `params object[] values`, so in order to pass the string array as single variable, you need to cast it to `object`, otherwise since `string[]` is castable to `object[]`, it will be passed as `variables` and the `@0` will basically refer to `strs[0]`.

Second, once you pass the `strs` correctly, for some reason you have to use `outerIt` inside the `Contains` method to access the entity property.

P.S. Another way is to get rid of the `strs` array and use the following criteria:

```
query = query.Where("Name.Substring(0, 1) >= \"0\" and Name.Substring(0, 1) <= \"9\"");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it has been solved. using outerIt and (object) in where clause :-)